# Chose scale in coordinate system

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, system, coordinate

what I am currently trying to create is a coordinate system that visualizes some data. I don't want to use an existing framework, but would like to create it from scratch.

What I have are three points, e.g. (15, 20), (-5,1), (120,-17). They define the scale of the coordinate system with x-min = -5 and x-max = 120 and y-min = -17 and x-max = 20. This scale is what I cant quite find as it should be meaningful. In this example it wouldn't make sense to have the coordinate system reaching from (-100, -100) to (100,100) with one mark every 10.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawShape(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  if (canvas.getContext){

    //draw canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var canvasBorder = Math.floor(canvas.scrollHeight * 0.1);
    var xLength = Math.floor(canvas.scrollWidth - (canvasBorder * 2));
    var yLength = Math.floor(canvas.scrollHeight - (canvasBorder * 2));

    //draw coordinate system
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(canvasBorder, canvasBorder);  //30,30
    context.lineTo(canvasBorder, canvasBorder + yLength); //30,270
    context.lineTo(canvasBorder + xLength, canvasBorder + yLength); //370,30
    context.stroke();

    //easy: define 5 values for x-axis
    var xMaxValue = 5;
    var tmp = Math.floor(xLength / xMaxValue);

    for(i = 0; i <= xMaxValue; i++){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(canvasBorder + tmp*i, canvasBorder + yLength);
        context.lineTo(canvasBorder + tmp*i, canvasBorder + yLength+10);
        context.fillText(i, canvasBorder + tmp*i, canvasBorder + yLength+10);
        context.stroke();
    }

    //difficult: have a max value for y-axis
    //too much space between 117 and 200, should display 120 or 150 instead
    //next level, what happens with -20 instead of 0 for min-y
    var yMaxValue = 117;
    var yIncrement = Math.pow(10, (Math.abs(Math.floor(yMaxValue)).toString().length)) / 10;
    var topValue = Math.floor(yMaxValue / yIncrement) + 1;

    var tmp = parseInt(yLength / topValue);

    for(i = 0; i <= topValue; i++){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(canvasBorder, yLength + canvasBorder - tmp*i);
        context.lineTo(canvasBorder - 10, yLength + canvasBorder - tmp*i);
        context.fillText(yIncrement * i, canvasBorder - 10, yLength + canvasBorder - tmp*i);
        context.stroke();
    }


  } else {
    alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
  }
}
</script>


</head>

<body onload="drawShape();">
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #ddd;">
</canvas>


</body>

</html>
```

Or is there a better way to take data create a coordinate system accordingly?

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Where are you getting your values for your coordinates? I'm assuming they're dynamic somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to map your actual values into a more traditional range for display on your chart.

For example, assume:

- Your actual values range from -17 to 120.
- You want to map these actual values into a more traditional range of 0 to 100.

Here's a function that maps a value from your actual range into a different range.

```
function remap(value, actualMin, actualMax, newMin, newMax) {
    return(newMin + (newMax - newMin) * (value - actualMin) / (actualMax - actualMin);
}
```

For example, to remap your actual value of 33 (range -17 to 120) into the range of 0-100:

```
remappedValue = remap( 33,  -17,120,  0,100 );
```

Note that the example new range of 0-100 is just an example.

You could use any range you desire for newMin to newMax.

Comment: That's great, I will start testing that. Thanks!